# From 1 to N how many pairs have LCM = N?

Tags: algorithm, number-theory, lcm

Suppose N = 8. There are 4 pairs (1,8),(2,8),(4,8),(8,8) whose LCM is 8. If N = 6. Then there are 5 pairs (1,6),(2,6),(2,3),(3,6),(6,6) whose LCM is 6. Now I want to know how to find the number of pairs quickly?

Comment: YOUR SHIFT KEY IS STUCK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question ["Pairs of numbers with at given LCM"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4152) at math.stackexchange.com gives the formula

```
((2e1+1)(2e2+1)...(2ek+1)+1)/2
        where e1, e2, ... is the exponents for the unique prime factors of n
```

for this number.

*i.e.*
8 = 2^3 has ((2*3+1)+1)/2 = 4 such pairs,
6 = 2^1 * 3^1 has ((2*1+1)(2*1+1)+1)/2 = 5 such pairs, and
60 = 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1 has ((2*2+1)(2*1+1)(2*1+1)+1)/2 = 23 such pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a similar question over here 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/pairs-of-numbers-with-a-given-lcm 
basically if n=(p1^e1)*(p2^e2)*...(pk^ek) where pi is prime for 1<=i<=k
then the solution would be ((2e1+1)*(2e2+1)*...(2ek+1)+1)/2